# How to add fade in/out animation for making a Grid visible programmatically

Tags: windows-phone

I am working on a Windows phone app.
I have a Grid which normally is Collapsed. But in some situation, I will programmatically change its visibility to become visible.  My question is 'Is it possible to add some fade in/out animation for changing the panel from Collapsed to Visible?
If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the Opacity property of the Grid. When your grid is to be rendered visible you set the opacity to 0 and start the animation. Don't forget to set the visibility property to `Visible` before you start the animation and back to `Collapsed` when fading out.

[MSDN: Opacity animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746779(v=vs.110).aspx)